# PHP date time from string

Tags: php

I need to convert string to date in below format, but I am not getting any result.

Below is the code, which doesn't print any date after converting.

```
$dt="2015/09/10 11:03:48";
$tmpDate = date_create_from_format('Y/m/d H:i:s', $dt);
echo $dt." = " . date("Y/m/d H:i:s", $tmpDate)."<br>"; // just to make sure the conversion is correct
```

Comment: `Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, object given` - is what you *should* be getting back.

Comment: `date_create_from_format()` creates a [DateTime object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), not a unix timestamp.... use the object's [format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method to format it to a string

Comment: echo $dt." = " . date("Y/m/d H:i:s", strtotime($dt))."<br>";

Comment: @rdanusha why!!!